# Anomaly Detection for Shifting Patterns

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, outliers, multivariate-normal-distribution, anomaly-detection

Suppose I build a model(e.g. Mahalanobis distance) to learn the normal pattern shown in green dots of the below plot. Then it is deployed into the production to detect anomalies. But as daily customer volume and daily sales increase over time, the normal pattern will gradually shift upward and rightward, as shown in blue dots. As a result, this model will fail. It doesn't make sense to rebuild the model everyday for this case either. How should I design an anomaly detection process to account for such shifting patterns?

[image]

Comment: Try first a time-series model of customers and sales, and use predicted values?

Comment: Some outliers only can be identified when looking both variables at the same time.